# using charindex and ltrim

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column where datas are like this

```
 DOESTOEIVSKI ALEXANDER
JAMES JOYCE
ROBERT LUDLUM
 MURAKAMI HARUKU
```

**Aim**: Make the first string have an upper case letter and the rest lower case and the second string keep it upper case

I've done it with the query #1:

```
SELECT (UPPER(LEFT(PARTPPHY.IDENTITE,1))
+LOWER(SUBSTRING( PARTPPHY.IDENTITE, 2, CHARINDEX( ' ', PARTPPHY.IDENTITE ) - 1))
+SUBSTRING(PARTPPHY.IDENTITE,CHARINDEX( ' ', PARTPPHY.IDENTITE ),DATALENGTH(PARTPPHY.IDENTITE))),PARTPPHY.IDENTITE) 
AS IDENTITE 
FROM PARTPPHY
```

Issue with #1 is I have that

```
 DOESTOEIVSKI ALEXANDER
James JOYCE
Murakami HARUKU
 ROBERT LUDLUM
```

I would like to have the same result for `DOESTOEIVSKI` or `ROBERT`

I tried the ltrim as you can see below for query #2:

```
SELECT UPPER(LEFT(LTRIM(PARTPPHY.IDENTITE),1))
+LOWER(SUBSTRING(LTRIM(PARTPPHY.IDENTITE), 2, CHARINDEX( ' ', LTRIM(PARTPPHY.IDENTITE)) - 1))
+SUBSTRING(LTRIM(PARTPPHY.IDENTITE),CHARINDEX( ' ', LTRIM(PARTPPHY.IDENTITE) ),DATALENGTH(LTRIM(PARTPPHY.IDENTITE))) 
AS IDENTITE 
FROM PARTPPHY
```

Issue is I have this error

> Msg 537, level 16, State 2, Ligne 17
>   Parameter length non valid for LEFT or SUBSTRING.

Yet when I'm trying that with query #3 (see below), things are fine

```
SELECT UPPER(LEFT(LTRIM(' JEAN TOTOT'),1))
+LOWER(SUBSTRING(LTRIM(' JEAN TOTOT'), 2, CHARINDEX( ' ', LTRIM(' JEAN TOTOT')) - 1))
+SUBSTRING(LTRIM(' JEAN TOTOT'),CHARINDEX( ' ', LTRIM(' JEAN TOTOT') ),DATALENGTH(LTRIM(' JEAN TOTOT')))
```

Can anyone give me an explanation?

Thanks

**Update**: After Zohar's comment, I had a look at the data definition of the field. It is an identity one... I think it does make a difference but I'm not sure how or why...

*DDL*:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PARTPPHY1](
[IU_PART_PP] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[TITRE] [int] NULL,
[NOM_NAISSANCE] [varchar](100) NULL,
[NOM_USAGE] [varchar](100) NULL,
[PRENOM] [varchar](20) NULL,
[AUTRES_PRENOMS] [varchar](60) NULL,
[IDENTITE]  AS ((([PRENOM]+' ')
+case when isnull([NOM_USAGE],'')='' 
then [NOM_NAISSANCE] else [NOM_USAGE] end)
+case when nullif([NOM_USAGE],'') IS NULL then '' else (' (NEE '+[NOM_NAISSANCE])+')' end))
```

*DML*

```
INSERT INTO PARTPPHY (IU_PART_PP,NOM_NAISSANCE,PRENOM)
VALUES(1,'BOUDJENAH','MICHEL')
INSERT INTO PARTPPHY ([IU_PART_PP],[NOM_NAISSANCE],[PRENOM])
VALUES(1,'','MIKE') 
INSERT INTO PARTPPHY ([IU_PART_PP],[NOM_NAISSANCE],[PRENOM])
VALUES(1,'DOE','JOHN') 
INSERT INTO PARTPPHY ([IU_PART_PP],[NOM_NAISSANCE],[PRENOM])
VALUES(1,'SMITH','STAN')
INSERT INTO PARTPPHY ([IU_PART_PP],[NOM_NAISSANCE],[PRENOM])
VALUES(1,'OPRAH','')
INSERT INTO PARTPPHY ([IU_PART_PP],[NOM_NAISSANCE],[PRENOM])
VALUES(1,'DESI','LU') 
INSERT INTO PARTPPHY ([IU_PART_PP],[NOM_NAISSANCE],[PRENOM])
VALUES(1,'JORDAN MIKE',NULL)
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the error.

Comment: Hi @ZoharPeled, thanks for answering. Please see my update

Comment: Please edit your question to include the relevant table DDL and sample data as DML

Comment: Thinking about it, I have enough ammo to fix this problem by myself but it would be great to figure out why the identity is causing problems

Comment: There are some things I do not understand: In your table you have the two parts of the name separated. Why is there a need to work with a concatenated string? The sample data you provide are not consistent in the order of first- and lastname... How is this possible? What about people with a mid-initial or a firstname like `Marc Eric` or something like `O'Hara`?

Comment: Hi @Shnugo, it is in France. There are no `O'Hara`'s. Midname are not taken into account. For the why, I dread to ask the 'technical architect'...

Comment: After a closer look: You are using the computed column `IDENTITE` in your first attempt. Wouldn't it be much better to change the implementation there to build this content correctly right from the start?

Comment: @Shnugo as I said I have enough ammo to fix this issue but still I would like to know why identity does not do the trick

Comment: @AndyK, I have no idea what *why identity does not do the trick* should mean. `IDENTITY` is nothing more than a automatic counter to give a unique ID to a row. For your case: I'd build an UDF with your nameparts as parameters to return a properly built string. This you might put as computed column, or better create a `VIEW` and speak with this table via this `VIEW`. Search for *proper-case*, there are many examples around

Comment: Close to 3 years ago, I started to use SO and I was very unknowledgeable. Close to 3 years after, I'm more knowledgeable (tiny bit), thanks to everyone who helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

below line is causing issue, when PRENOM has empty value CHARINDEX will give 0, so SUBSTRING has last value as -1!

```
CHARINDEX( ' ', LTRIM(PARTPPHY.IDENTITE)) - 1)
```

try this, it will check first if there are both part of the string available then use the logic for both string parts, else use other logic.

```
SELECT IDENTITE,
    CASE WHEN CHARINDEX( ' ', LTRIM(PARTPPHY.IDENTITE)) > 0 THEN
        UPPER(LEFT(LTRIM(PARTPPHY.IDENTITE),1))
        +LOWER(SUBSTRING(LTRIM(PARTPPHY.IDENTITE), 2, CHARINDEX( ' ', LTRIM(PARTPPHY.IDENTITE)) - 1 ))
        +SUBSTRING(LTRIM(PARTPPHY.IDENTITE),CHARINDEX( ' ', LTRIM(PARTPPHY.IDENTITE) ),DATALENGTH(LTRIM(PARTPPHY.IDENTITE))) 
    ELSE
        UPPER(LEFT(LTRIM(PARTPPHY.IDENTITE),1))
        + ISNULL(LOWER(STUFF(LTRIM(PARTPPHY.IDENTITE), 1,1, '')),'')    
    END
AS IDENTITE1
FROM PARTPPHY
```

Comment: Hi @jatin-patel, your answer is sound. I've seen that and it bugged me a bit but I was unsure of what to do ... I need to have a try with a `CASE`

Comment: magic. True I thought about it but I did not push into that direction. Thank.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that works:

```
SELECT  IDENTITE,
        LEFT(LTRIM(IDENTITE), 1) + 
        LOWER(SUBSTRING(LTRIM(IDENTITE), 2, CHARINDEX(' ', LTRIM(IDENTITE) + ' ') - 1)) + 
        CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(' ', LTRIM(RTRIM(IDENTITE))) > 0 THEN
            RIGHT(IDENTITE, LEN(IDENTITE) -  CHARINDEX(' ', LTRIM(IDENTITE)))
        ELSE '' END
FROM PARTPPHY
WHERE IDENTITE IS NOT NULL
```

Your problem was that you have data where there is no space in the middle.

Comment: Thanks @zohard-peled for your help and pushing me into the right direction

Answer (score 1):

Try like this,

```
SELECT upper(left(identite, 1)) + lower(substring(identite, 2, charindex(' ', identite) - 1)) + upper(substring(identite, charindex(' ', identite) + 1, len(identite))) AS identite
FROM PARTPPHY
```

Comment: @AndyK *does not work* is no help, neither is *nope alas...*. Please state the actual details...

Comment: @Shnugo fair enough. This is the results http://i.stack.imgur.com/bpwCe.png As you can see ` SCHMITT NORBERT` still has a ` ` before the  `SCHMITT`

Comment: Thanks @StackUser for your help

Answer (score 1):

The capitalization issue is nothing at all to do with identity or the calculated column.

You have leading space for  `DOESTOEIVSKI ALEXANDER` and  `MURAKAMI HARUKU`. Your formula capitalizes after the first space you find. Hence the whole name is capitalized.

This is why adding LTRIM fixed the problem.